# Сохранение значений динамически созданных inputText в таблице dataTable в массив JSF

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf

имеется таблица

```
    <h:panelGroup>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        <br/>
            <h:dataTable value="#{ datacontroller.getList()}" 
             var="value"    styleClass="table table-bordered">

                 <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Data</f:facet>
                    <h:form>
                        <h:inputText value="#{data.inputvalue}> </h:inputText>
                    </h:form>
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable>
        </div>
    </div>

   </h:panelGroup>
```

Метод getList() возвращает ArrayList определенной длины например [a,b,c], основании которой строится таблица с тремя полями ввода (). В этих полях вводятся числовые значения.

```
  @Named
  @SessionScoped
  public class Data implements Serializable {

private String inputvalue;



public String getInputvalue() {
    return inputvalue;
}
public void setInputvalue(String inputvalue) {
    this.inputvalue = inputvalue;
}
```

Необходимо введенные в этих полях значения обработать в другом методе calculate() который вызывается кнопкой "OK".

```
  <h:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{datacontroller.calculate()}" />
```

Как сохранить введенные значения в этих полях и и обработать? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таким образом, как в Вашем примере, получится три формы (или какой длины там будет список). Никакими доступными средствами их не сохранить вместе за один раз.
Формы работают независимо друг от друга.
Форма должна обрамлять все свои поля и кнопки.
Потом Вы пишите в datatable `var="value"`, а в column используете какой-то `data`.  Какое имя задали переменной, такое и надо использовать.

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:dataTable value="#{datacontroller.list}" styleClass="table table-bordered"
                 var="data">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Data</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{data.inputvalue}"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{datacontroller.calculate}"/>
    ...
</h:form>
```

Контролёр

```
public class Datacontroller {
    private List<Data> list;
    ...
    List<Data> getList() { 
        if (list == null) list = ... // создать и заполнить
        return list;
    }
    ...
    public void calculate() {
        ...
        for (Data data : getList()) {
            String inputvalue = data.getInputvalue();
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Data

```
public class Data {
    private String inputvalue;

    public String getInputvalue() {
        return inputvalue;
    }

    public void setInputvalue(String inputvalue) {
        this.inputvalue = inputvalue;
    }
}
```

Если data есть `List<String>`, то как здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236170/using-hdatatablehinputtext-on-a-liststring-doesnt-update-model-values

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:dataTable value="#{datacontroller.list}" styleClass="table table-bordered"
                 var="data"
                 binding="#{table}">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Data</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{datacontroller.list[table.rowIndex]}"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{datacontroller.calculate}"/>
    ...
</h:form>
```

Можно изменять элемент списка по индексу. Чтобы получить индекс в данном случае используется приём с `binding`-ом таблицы к переменной `table`. Через `table` получаем возможность извлечь свойства таблицы (и не только). Так `table.rowIndex` - индекс текущей строки. Что нам и требуется. Сама переменная `table` создаётся автоматически в request scope.

Контролёр

```
public class Datacontroller {
    private List<String> list;
    ...
    List<String> getList() { 
        if (list == null) list = ... // создать и заполнить
        return list;
    }
    ...
    public void calculate() {
        ...
        for (String data : getList()) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: но если я пишу value="#{data.inputvalue}"  то появляется ошибка предупреждение. Задача стоит в сохранении введенных данных в ArrayList в bean-не.    Нашел ссылку http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747157/how-to-save-hinputtext-values-of-a-hdatatable-my-attempt-only-saves-the-value     Но тоже не совсем понятно

Comment: Какое ещё предупреждение? У самого таблицы там и тут и нормально всё.Что за список `getList()`? `ArrayList<Data>?` Кажет понял. Это потому что Ваша `Data` `@Named @SessionScoped` за каким-то ... Думаю тут конфликт названий происходит. Напишите вместо data что-нибудь другое. Хоть тот же `value`, только чтобы везде одинаково. и в var и в input. `var="value"` `<h:input value="#{value.inputvalue}"/>`

Comment: ну в смысле желтой волнистой линией подчеркивается. в методе getList() возвращается значение ArrayList<String>

Comment: поменял все равно не работает

Comment: Не просто так же подчёркивается. Должно быть какое-то пояснение. А если `ArrayList<String>`, то откуда у `String` свойство `inputvalue` скажите пожалуйста? Тогда следовало бы писать просто `<h:input value="#{value}"/>`. Но и это не сработает. Для редактирования требуется, чтобы элементами списка были или bean или map. Редактируется не элемент списка, а свойства элемента. У Stringa ничего нет, что можно было бы изменять.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236170/using-hdatatablehinputtext-on-a-liststring-doesnt-update-model-values

Comment: спасибо за пример. но пока не работает. а что вместо [table.rowIndex] писать? если я table пишу то он выделяется желтой линией

Comment: Жёлтая не красная. IDE не всё может распознать. Так ей ничего не известно о `table`, её свойства и методах, вот и беспокоится. Напрасно я надеюсь. Надо просто запустить на исполнение и посмотреть что будет. Если что сверить свойства `table` с javadoc по компонентам. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlDataTable.html показывает, что есть такое `getRowIndex()` - значит тут всё нормально должно быть

Comment: при наведении мышкой на  [table.rowIndex] появляется сообщение Configure Problem Severity for preference 'Property cannot be 
 resolved'

Comment: `Property cannot be resolved` - не может распознать свойство. Что не удивительно в данном случае. Часто не распознаются даже вполне  очевидные вещи, а `table` в программе появится только во время выполнения.

Comment: Возможно я неправильно описал задачу. В целом имеется List<String>. например [a,b,c]. на основании него должны строиться inputtext в данном случае 3. Но в них не должно быть никаких значений. Только если пользователь введет в них значения и нажмет на кнопку например <input type="submit" value="Submit" />  или <h:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{datacontroller.createArray()}" /> то значения введенных пользователем данных должны в Бине добавляться в другой ArrayList<String>

Comment: Выше указанные примеры думаю что просто заполняют inputtext значениями из list

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39461/discussion-between--and-sergey).

Comment: Sergey, cпасибо за пример все работает.